# setup intellij to ask type parameter when using generics in java

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA. I used to use Eclipse.

By default, IntelliJ doesn't ask to give parameter type for Java Generics Type.

```
// Following code doesn't give any warning
List list = null;

// I want to make IntelliJ ask me to specify type parameter (say Long)
List<Long> list = null; // i.e  If I want a List of Long
```

**How can I set up IntelliJ so that it ask me to give generic type parameters while using generics java types?**

I'm using JDK 8 if it matters.

Comment: You should search for anything related to *Raw type warnings*, and it's rather odd that it doesn't trigger a warning by default. One caveat here is that you are holding a reference to a raw type, but constructing a non-raw type, which might confuse the IDE.

Comment: @skiwi Thanks. It's under "Inspections" in project settings. I can set different level of warnings/errors from there. But it's still now much friendly as it was in Eclipse.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Actually, I was referring to generics parameter type in `List` rather than that diamond operator after `ArrayList`.

Comment: How is it that you want the IDE to read your mind? This last edit makes the question look less clear than the previous version.

Comment: @RyanJ Earlier, the question was misunderstood with diamond operator.
And Eclipse ask to give type parameter for `List` if code is `List list = null;` And it's not mind reading.

Comment: Your code explicitly says you want the IDE to tell you to declare a generic type of Long, assuming you want a List of Long. It has no idea what kind of list you want, so the question should be framed around the desire to be warned about a missing generic type in general, not a recommendation for a specific one. It's a small distinction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IntelliJ provide an inspection name **Raw use of parameterized class**

[image]

After enabling that inspection.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the `Project Structure` menu, under `Project`, check the language level setting. Setting it to `6.0` will cause the IDE to give you an error when you are missing the identifier in the diamond block.

Setting it to 7.0 or higher will suppress it.

**Addition based on further exchange:**

Under `File -> Settings -> Inspections -> General` if the box that says `Unchecked warning` is checked, when you run `Analyze -> Inspect code`, it will report the condition noted under `General -> Unchecked warnings` as "Unchecked call to add(E) as a member of raw type 'java.util.List'", in this example. If you declare the generic type of List explicitly, this warning will not show up in the report.

Comment: No, it doesn't show warning even if I set "Project Language Level" to `1.6`.

Comment: I use IntelliJ out of the box, and when I use `6.0 - @Override in Interfaces` I get an error that says `Identifier Expected` and it prevents me from compiling. I've pasted your code exactly how you've typed it. When I change to `7.0` or higher (which is when the <> operator was officially supported), it does not produce an error. If you go by the methodology that all warnings should be treated as errors, I would think this would be a better solution than the one you're ultimately seeking.

Comment: I'm familiar with diamond operator in `7.0` but what I really wanted to do was the type parameter for `List` which take a generic type parameter.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you, since the syntax is valid for the version of Java that you are using. If you actually use the `Analyze -> Inspect Code` option in the IDE, it will catch this condition under `General -> Unchecked warnings`. It's not explicitly called out, but it will report all warnings issued by the compiler in the report.

Comment: Some times, adding an explicit language level also helps Intellij for maven projects to override the defaults.

`<plugin> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> <configuration> <source>1.7</source> <target>1.7</target> </configuration> </plugin>`

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to get it to do exactly what you are asking for; however, once you would instantiate your List and then add an element to it IntelliJ will mark it with a yellow squiggly line and warn you it was unchecked. If you would put your cursor anywhere on the yellow squiggly and press Alt-Enter it will offer you "Try to generify YourClassName", press enter and it will infer the type and modify your code.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks. that's helpful. But, is there no way to make IntelliJ ask me to specify type parameter when I declare `List`?

Comment: I am not aware of a way of getting IntelliJ to do what you want. However, I am curious how what you want to do saves you any keystrokes. You want IntelliJ to offer you a dialog to enter the type in, how is that easier than just typing the type in the code? If you type the type on the left side IntelliJ will enter the type on the right side if you use code completion (not necessary at the 1.7 code level of course).